# How to write a condition inside a jinja expression

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja expression as:

```
{% if meaning['example'] %}
    {{ meaning['example'] }}<br>
{% endif %}
```

Which gives me o/p:

```
you don't know jack
```

Here `word['word']` has the value `jack` in the o/p

How can I make the `jack` bold in the expression?

WRT SO I have tried as:

```
{{ <strong>word['words']</strong> if word['words'] in meaning['example'] }}
```

But this didn't work , Any help is much appreciated , TIA

Comment: You just have to write the html tags outside the expression. And also the jinja expression are calculated on serverside.

Comment: I have this value in variable `meaning['example']` ->you don't know jack and  variable `word['words']` holds jack as value , so I need to bold the value jack in the sentence .....hope it's clear

Comment: Another thing you can do is split the string, loop over it and check each word if the belong to the "word" list then make them bold and the rest print as it is. example  for split {% list1 = variable1.split(';') %} .

Comment: the whole thing as {% set str =meaning['example'].split('') %} and then {% for word['word'] in str %} ....?

Comment: @MayankJain I'm little confused , can you please help me out with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

### in an `if` block

```html
{% if word['words'] in meaning['example'] %}
    <strong>word['words']</strong> }}
{% endif %}
```

### in a ternary if expression

```html
{{ '<strong>' + word['words'] + '</strong>' if word['words'] in meaning['example'] else '' }}
```

I personally prefer the first option if I want to write markup, or the conditional expression is relatively long as in your example.

Comment: I think the question is about that he want to write the whole string with some words bold...

Comment: @MayankJain Exactly and that some words are in variable , here in E.g. `word['words']` holds jack

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if meaning['example'] %}
    {% for w in meaning['example'] %}
        {% if w == word['word']%}
            <strong>{{w}} </strong>
        {% else %}
               {{w}} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

if you have number of word then replace

{% if w == word['word']%}  -->>  {% if w in word %}

Comment: This would be example on how to do it , thanks mate but the solution to my Q is different

Answer (score 0):

For anyone's ref

Thanks for @Mayank Jain comment from where i digged this solution for my Q :

```
                        {% if meaning['example'] %}
                            {% for w in meaning['example'].split(' ') %}
                                {% if w == word['word']%}
                                    <strong>{{w}} </strong>
                                {% else %}
                                       {{w}}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
```